# How to discard result set from statement like REPAIR TABLE in stored procedure of MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc

Is it possible to discard the result set of stored procedure which are not results from SELECT statement?

If it is impossible from MySQL, is it possible from JDBC?

The reason is that in our stored procedure, `REPAIR TABLE` is called in case of exception (in stored procedure) as table may crash. However there is a side effect of calling `REPAIR TABLE`, it returns over 200MB of result set ("The REPAIR TABLE statement might produce many rows of information for each repaired table." as stated in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/repair-table.html).

I know the result set was returned from `REPAIR TABLE` as I analyzed the heap dump from Java OutOfMemoryError happened in production.